# EJB Dependencies are not wired (injected) properly on GlassFish 2.1

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, ejb-3.0

For some reason I should use old EJB container GlassFish 2.1.1. (certified for Java EE 5 and EJB 3.0). The project structure is following:

MDB:

```
@MessageDriven(
   mappedName = "jms/Queue",
   activationConfig = {
      @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", 
                                propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")    
})
public class TriggerMBean implements MessageListener {
     @EJB
     private TriggerProcessor triggerService; 

     public void onMessage(Message message) {
          //.......
          triggerService.process();
          //.......
     }
}
```

TriggerProcessor:

```
@Stateless
public class TriggerProcessor {
    public void proceess() {
        //....
    }
}
```

I have not created deployment descriptor. As I understand, it's not necessary if I'm using annotations and EJB version starting from 3.0

While deploying, exception is the following:

```
[#|2012-06-15T15:55:50.290+0300|SEVERE|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.mdb|_ThreadID=42;_ThreadName=p: thread-pool-1; w: 61;_RequestID=824fc411-7772-42cc-aeee-9a8d9b451dbf;|com.sun.enterprise.InjectionException
com.sun.enterprise.InjectionException: Exception attempting to inject Unresolved Ejb-Ref fi.prh.novus.sync.consumer.TriggerMBean/triggerService@jndi: fi.prh.novus.sync.service.TriggerProcessor@null@fi.prh.novus.sync.service.TriggerProcessor@Session@null into class fi.prh.novus.sync.consumer.TriggerMBean
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:387)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:206)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:127)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.createMessageDrivenEJB(MessageBeanContainer.java:711)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.access$100(MessageBeanContainer.java:109)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer$MessageBeanContextFactory.create(MessageBeanContainer.java:492)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.util.pool.NonBlockingPool.getObject(NonBlockingPool.java:199)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer._getContext(MessageBeanContainer.java:555)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.getContext(BaseContainer.java:1731)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanContainer.beforeMessageDelivery(MessageBeanContainer.java:1008)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.MessageBeanListenerImpl.beforeMessageDelivery(MessageBeanListenerImpl.java:70)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.inflow.MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.invoke(MessageEndpointInvocationHandler.java:135)
        at $Proxy86.beforeDelivery(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.OnMessageRunner.run(OnMessageRunner.java:245)
        at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.work.OneWork.doWork(OneWork.java:77)
        at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:555)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: fi.prh.novus.sync.service.TriggerProcessor#fi.prh.novus.sync.service.TriggerProcessor not found
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:216)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:188)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:74)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:111)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:409)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.NamingManagerImpl.lookup(NamingManagerImpl.java:951)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.java.javaURLContext.lookup(javaURLContext.java:173)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:407)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at com.sun.enterprise.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:287)
        ... 15 more
|#]
```

I tried to annotate `private TriggerProcessor triggerService;` with `@EJB(beanName="TriggerProcessor")` and `public class TriggerProcessor {..` with `@Stateless(name="TriggerProcessor")` but it didn't help.

Actually, this perfectly works on newest Glassfish 3.1., but as I told preciously, I should use GF 2.1.1.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wan't work since GlassFish 2 does not support EJB 3.1. The `TriggerProcessor` ony offers a no-interface view since it doesn't implement any interface. Your must provide an interface for the `TriggerProcessor` to be compliant with EJB 3.0.

Only EJB 3.1 supports no-interface views. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4496/beahm/index.html and chapter *1.2 What is New in EJB 3.1* of the JSR 318 specification.

Comment: Glassfish 2.1.x does support EJB 3.0 http://glassfish.java.net/public/comparing_v2_and_v3.html

Comment: You are right. Sorry. I correted this. But the no-interface view was introduced with EJB 3.1.

Comment: Thank you very much for response! Could you please explain a little bit closer? Should I create an interface and implement it by TriggerProcessor, and pass interface reference to TriggerMBean? How should I annotate this interface?

Comment: I would create an interface for the processor and annoatet it with the `@Local` annotation. Could you try it?